# How add correctly the appcompat library to android project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, facebook-android-sdk, android-appcompat

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        // Configuration for Fabric
        jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

dependencies {
    // 'jar' files in '/libs' folder
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'

    // Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.+@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    // Configuration for Fabric
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion 22

    // Define current date and time now to have the same all along the build
    def currentDate = getCurrentDate()
def currentDateAndTime = getCurrentDateAndTime()

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2.7
        versionName name
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            flavorDimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        arm {
            flavorDimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        // Configuration for release candidates
        release {

            // Proguard configuration
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFile 'procfg.pro'

        }


    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

After add the dependency to appcompat:

```
....
dependencies {
    // new dependency added
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    // 'jar' files in '/libs' folder
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'

    // Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.+@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
....
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"textAllCaps\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"<dir>/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"track\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"<dir>/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"thumbTextPadding\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"<dir>/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"switchMinWidth\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"<dir>/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"Attribute \"switchPadding\" has already been defined","sourcePath":"<dir>/colors.xml","position":{"startLine":1},"original":""}
```

I have defined none of this values in my color.xml file. I guess the problem could be related to the facebook sdk library.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Post the other dependencies

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I added the dependencies.

Comment: Are you using some jars?

Comment: Yes: FlurryAnalytics-4.1.0 , newrelic.android , PayPalAndroidSDK , PDFNet , Tools (pdfTron) and WebtrendsAndroidClientLib

Answer (score 0):

First you can try with the latest v22 of appcompat-v7 22.2.1.
If you still have the problem, check the list of dependencies by using gradle with the name of your module:dependencies. If my module is app try in a terminal:

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

(or gradlew if you are using the graddle wrapper).
You should have something like this:

```
 +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1
    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1
    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1
    \--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0
         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22) -> 22.2.1 (*)
         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0
```

You can see that both appcompat-v7 and facebook-android-sdk own support-v4.
To exclude the support-v4 from the facebook sdk, you will have to write:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0') {
    exclude group:'com.android.support', module: "support-v4"
}
```

If you run the previous gradle app:dependencies, you will see that now the facebook sdk doesn't have support-v7 in its sub directories.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Currently the latest version of appcompat is not 22.2.1, but 23.0.0

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have say the latest version for the api 22.

Comment: I have excluded the support-v4 from Facebook and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @JoseF When you gradle app:dependencies, do you see another duplicated dependency ? (marked with a *)

Comment: Yes, I see  "com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.0.1 (*)" and "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 (*)"

Comment: Do you have a custom class for switches ? Because all the 5 attributes (textAllCaps, track, thumbTextPadding, switchMinWidth and switchPadding) come from there.

Comment: You can still try to clean your build  and rebuild it on android studio. `File- > Invalidate cache /restart...` to see if the problem can be solved in this way.